# Maxwell- Faraday's Equation, MotionalEmf, Work Done by Lorentz Force

Tags: electromagnetism, work

A moving rod placed in a stationary U-shaped frame.

When a conductor (the moving rod in this case) moves perpendicular to a magnetic field, an electromotive force (EMF) is induced according to Faraday's law of electromagnetic induction. The rate of change of magnetic flux through the loop formed by the moving rod and the stationary U-shaped rods is given by = B⋅L⋅V
where B is the magnetic field strength,L is the length of the rod, and
v is its velocity.

Now, the negative of rate of change of magnetic flux = work done by electromagnetic force throughout the loop, which is BLV+IR, i=current , r=resistance

But this leads to that,BLV=BLV+I--->>IR=0 , means electric current through loop is 0, So, Just Please Clarify My Confusion

Answer (score 0):

The emf induced in a rod of length $\ell$ travelling with speed $v$ in a plane perpendicular to a magnetic field $B$ is $B\ell v$.
If the resistance of the complete circuit is $R$ then the power dissipated in the circuit is $\dfrac{(B\ell v)^2}{R}= \dfrac{B^2\ell^2 v^2}{R}$.

A current carrying conductor moving in a magnetic field experiences a force acting on it $B I\ell$ where $I$ is the current in the circuit, $\dfrac{B\ell v}{R}$.

For the rod to move at constant velocity, $v$, an external force, $\dfrac{B\ell v}{R}$ must be applied to the rod and the work done per second by the external force is $B I\ell\cdot v = B\cdot \dfrac{B\ell v}{R}\cdot \ell\cdot v  = \dfrac{B^2\ell^2 v^2}{R}$ which is exactly equal to the power dissipated in the circuit.

Comment: That's not what i asked.

Comment: The statement *the negative of rate of change of magnetic flux = work done by electromagnetic force throughout the loop, which is BLV+IR* is not correct.  $B\ell v$ is the induced emf and $IR$ is the potential difference across the resistance $R$.  These two quantities are equal in magnitude which means that the current in the circuit is $B\ell v/R$

Comment: MultiversalExplorers it is true that this answer is not what you asked for specifically, in fact your post had no question in it. Instead it had a request for clarification and if it is not clear yet then you should read Farcher's post more carefully a few mote times and next time ask a clear question.

Comment: If you equate line integral of lorentz force per coulomb of charge to negative rate of change of magnetic flux, then you will get, BLV+IR=BLV.

Comment: @MultiversalExplorers - You **either** treat the $B\ell v$ as an emf on the right hand side of the equation **or** the $B\ell v$ as a potential difference on the left hand side of the equation.  That term cannot be on both sides of the equation.

Comment: But in wikipedia it's given that line integral of lorentz force per coulomb of charge through loop= negative rate of change of magnetic flux through loop

Comment: In this case the line integral is for the resistive part of the circuit $IR$.